# Problem with delete separator using jQuery when word wrap to new string

Tags: html, jquery, css, word-wrap

I use a simple script to remove the separator, but sometimes it is not removed. Could someone help me finish the script so that it worked well?

```js
function sep() {
   var lastElement = false;
    $("ul li").each(function() {
        if (lastElement && lastElement.offset().left > $(this).offset().left) {
            $(lastElement).addClass("lastdot");
            $(this).addClass("firstdot");
       } else if (lastElement) {
            $(lastElement).removeClass("lastdot");
            $(this).removeClass("firstdot");
       }
        lastElement = $(this);
   });
}
```

```css
a {color:royalblue; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover, a:active {text-decoration:underline;}
ul {background-color:lightblue; color: black; text-align:center; padding:1em 0; margin:0;}
ul li {display:inline; white-space:nowrap;}
ul li::before {content:""; padding-right:3px;}
ul li::after {content:"*"; padding-left:3px;}
ul li.firstdot::before, ul li:first-child::before {content:"*"; color:transparent;}
ul li.lastdot::after,  ul li:last-child::after {color:transparent;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="sep();" onresize="sep();">

<ul >
<li>Red</li>
<li>Green</li>
<li>Orange</li>
<li>White</li>
<li>Black</li>
<li>Yellow</li>
<li>Light Blue</li>
<li>Magenta</li>
<li>Dark Cyan</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can try with css like **ul li:not(:last-child)**.

Answer (score 0):

solution: ul {font-size:0} li {font-size:16px}

```css
a {color:royalblue; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover, a:active {text-decoration:underline;}
ul {font-size: 0;background-color:lightblue; color: black; text-align:center; padding:1em 0; margin:0;}
ul li {font-size: 16px;display:inline; white-space:nowrap;}
ul li::before {content:""; padding-right:3px;}
ul li::after {content:"*"; padding-left:3px;}
ul li.firstdot::before, ul li:first-child::before {content:"*"; color:transparent;}
ul li.lastdot::after,  ul li:last-child::after {color:transparent;}
```

```html
<ul >
<li>Red</li>
<li>Green</li>
<li>Orange</li>
<li>White</li>
<li>Black</li>
<li>Yellow</li>
<li>Light Blue</li>
<li>Magenta</li>
<li>Dark Cyan</li>
</ul>
```